# Application is not able to connect to the database

Tags: oracle

Getting below error while connecting to database, please help me on this

```
02 Mar 2017 10:48:02,004 ERROR [FMGConnectionManager$DBConnectionPool]:1023:http-nio-8080-exec-1 - Can't create a new connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.48.135.217:1521/PM_PERF_S
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.48.135.217:1521/PM_PERF_S
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the old style (deprecated) SID based URL format with the new (recommended) service name based URL syntax.

If `PM_PERF_S` is the SID, then the URL should be:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.48.135.217:1521:PM_PERF_S
```

(note the `:` instead of the `/` before the SID).

If `PM_PERF_S` is the service name, the URL should be:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.48.135.217:1521/PM_PERF_S
```

(note the `//` after the `@`)

Comment: Well spotted, thoug I think that `No suitable driver found` rather points to my answer.

Comment: @ammoQ: "No suitable driver" can mean both: no driver class was found that handles Oracle connections. Or it can also mean that the  driver was found but it rejected the URL because it was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things to fix this kind of problem:

1. an Oracle JDBC driver .jar file in your classpath (e.g. `ojdbc6.jar`)
2. `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` in your code to register the driver

Comment: Hi Ammo, if in case ojdbc14.jar in classpath also i need to use same code as you mentioned above